# Control-M - analyze SQL Server output with On-Do Actions

Tags: sql-server, control-m

We are using Control-M to submit several batch jobs to a legacy application, but due to limitations, the only way to monitor their status is by querying the *Process* table of the DB.

`Process` table:

| JobNum | JobStat | Batch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finished | ABC |
| 2 | Failed | ABC |
| 3 | Started | ABC |
| 4 | Started | ABC |

I am trying use Cyclic Database job to query the Jobs, and rerun ever 5min while there are still jobs in `Started`, but have it break when:

- The query result is empty (No jobs exist for that batch) - set to `Not OK`
- **All** jobs are in either `Finished` or `Failed` in the batch - set to `OK`

Currently, I am trying to do something like:

```
SELECT 'TotalJobs', COUNT(JobNum)
FROM Process
WHERE Batch = 'ABC'

SELECT 'StartedJobs', COUNT(JobNum)
FROM Process
WHERE Batch = 'ABC'
  AND JobStat = 'Started'

SELECT 'CompletedJobs', COUNT(JobNum)
FROM Process
WHERE Batch = 'ABC'
  AND JobStat IN ('Finished', 'Failed')
```

Then using On-Do Actions with Specific statements like -

```
Statement: *
Code: TotalJob,0
Set-NotOK
```

```
Statement: *
Code: StartedJobs,0
Set-OK
```

But it does both actions.

Is this possible to do this more complex analysis with On-Do Actions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work, could you share a screenshot of the output (sysout) and the job log when it matches both scenarios (this will show what it has matched). Possibly the output is including more than intended.